# C++ library that include std::vector, std::array and std::span functionality but with different size types and with capacity versions

Tags: open-source, library, c++

It's pretty common I run into need to wrap C apis that only take 32bit integer, or 32bit unsigned arrays (or even smaller).   But passing either `std::span` or `std::vector` into these APIs causes my compiler to warn me about mismatched sizes, `std::size_t` being different than `std::int32_t` for example.  I'd like to find a library that provides the following:

- versions of `span`, `vector`, `array` which contain additional template parameter for the size type.
- versions of `array` and `vector` that have a fixed capacity, but variable size.

Does anything close to this exist for C++?

Comment: C++23 `std::mdspan` and the corresponding `std::extents` let you specify the index/size type.

Comment: The Guidelines Support Library (GSL) has `gsl::narrow` wrapping a `static_cast` but also checking if information is lost when casting which can be useful for interfacing with C APIs.

Comment: GSL has it's own `span` type and [gsl-lite](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite), a specific GSL implementation [lets you customize its index type](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite?tab=readme-ov-file#gsl_config_span_index_typestdsize_t), but only as a preprocessor macro, not as a template argument.

Answer (score 0):

After a short search I found [pector](https://github.com/aguinet/pector) which allows specifying the size/index type as a template parameter to its `vector` equivalent. It doesn't have equivalents to `span` or `array` though. Luckily both `span` and `array` are comparatively easy to implement yourself as you do not need to take care of memory management.